# Are there common types of human skeletons in gamedev industry?

Tags: skeletal-animation, 3d-modeling, skinning

I have to decide which human(oid) skeleton I'll choose to do procedural animation with it in the future. I'm looking for a flexible set of bones that would not lead to painful model reskinning later. Are there any well-known modern variants to compare?

Comment: Have you looked in your closet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed. Unity (for instance) will accept a fairly broad variety of rigs to be converted to Humanoid Avatars as long as they follow the same basic structure. Adobe's [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com) is one source of animations for rigs that conform to that structure; there are many others.

This is the "body" portion of Unity's humanoid Avatar configurator:
[image: Unity Avatar Configurator]

This is a fairly typical heirarchy that maps well to this system:
[image]

The rig itself looks like this:
[image]